# Different app.config appSettings based on app.config value

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, config, app-config

I have app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>       
        <!--One set of properties-->
        <add key="Condition" value="A"/>
        <add key="DependingPropertyA" value="B"/>
        <add key="DependingPropertyB" value="C"/>
        <!--Another set of properties-->
        <add key="Condition" value="B"/>
        <add key="DependingPropertyA" value="D"/>
        <add key="DependingPropertyB" value="E"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

So I want if Condition == A define one set of properties and if Condition == B - different set of properties so when I switch between A and B I don't need to change all other properties.
Is it possible?

Comment: is this for debug and release versions that must differ

Comment: No. This is not for debug/release configurations.

Comment: Check this one out http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property names are the same for each "Condition" (environment perhaps?), then you can do this with a little coding wizardry:

(App.Config:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>       

    <!--Condition 'selector', change value to 'CondB' when you want to switch-->
    <add key="Condition" value="CondA"/>

    <add key="CondA.DependingPropertyA" value="B"/>
    <add key="CondA.DependingPropertyB" value="C"/>
    <add key="CondB.DependingPropertyA" value="D"/>
    <add key="CondB.DependingPropertyB" value="E"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then, let's say, in your C# .NET code:

```
string keyPrepend = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Condition"];

string propAValue = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[String.Format("{0}.{1}", keyPrepend, "DependingPropertyA")];
string propBValue = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[String.Format("{0}.{1}", keyPrepend, "DependingPropertyB")];
```

This let's you switch which set of key/values you want to use based on a single Condition key's value.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking about this approach but I don't like it :( It will require to keep in mind that for some properties we need "special" names and for some we don't.

Comment: True. I usually try to abstract those things away from the core code and put them into a Helper/Utility class called "ConfigManager.cs" or something. You can make public properties for each setting, and have each setting know how to read itself from the App.Config. (I know some frown on Helper classes, for good reasons (IoC, DI), but I find them useful for simple things like this.) Anyways, this keeps your main code clean, calling 'ConfigManager.PropertyA', not littering it with AppSetting calls everywhere, and underneath the hood ConfigManager keep control over knowing where/how to get stuff.

Comment: Yes, of course it'll be wrapped in some kind of *Manager class.

Comment: I'm doing something very similar, but the issue is a third party SDK requires its key name in appSettings to match exactly, and I need two different values for this Key.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to come this way.
Custom section:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConditionalConfig
{
    public class ConditionalConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("selector", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public string Selector
        {
            get { return (string) base["selector"]; }
            set { base["selector"] = value; }
        }

        public new string this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                var result = Shared[key] ?? ((KeyValueConfigurationCollection) base[Selector])[key];
                return result != null ? result.Value : null;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public KeyValueConfigurationCollection Shared
        {
            get { return (KeyValueConfigurationCollection) base[""]; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("opt1", IsRequired = true)]
        public KeyValueConfigurationCollection Opt1
        {
            get { return (KeyValueConfigurationCollection) base["opt1"]; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("opt2", IsRequired = true)]
        public KeyValueConfigurationCollection Opt2
        {
            get { return (KeyValueConfigurationCollection) base["opt2"]; }
        }
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="conditional" type="ConditionalConfig.ConditionalConfigurationSection, ConditionalConfig" />
  </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <conditional selector="opt2">
    <add key="test" value="value"/>
    <opt1>
      <add key="test1" value="value1"/>
    </opt1>
    <opt2>
      <add key="test1" value="value2"/>
    </opt2>
  </conditional>
</configuration>
```

If only I could remove "public KeyValueConfigurationCollection Opt1" properties - it'd be perfect for me.